# How to upload Multiple Images and Files in one input field with Preview in jquery and Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, laravel

```
<div class="col-lg-12 mt-4">
                            <label for="file">{{ __('Upload Receipts/Bills (Multiple Document)') }}</label>
                            <div class="upload__box">
                                <div class="upload__btn-box">
                                  <label class="upload__btn">
                                    {{__('Upload Bills')}}
                          
                                    <input type="file" multiple="" id="files" name="files[]" data-max_length="20" class="upload__inputfile" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf">
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="upload__img-wrap"></div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
```

I'm trying to upload Multiple Images and Files with **preview and cancel** but unable to find any way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  ImgUpload();

  function ImgUpload() {
    var imgWrap = "";
    var imgArray = [];

    $('.upload__inputfile').each(function () {
      $(this).on('change', function (e) {
        imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
        var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');

        var files = e.target.files;
        var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
        var iterator = 0;


        filesArr.forEach(function (f, index) {

          // if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          // return;
          // }

          if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
            return false
          } else {
            var len = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
              if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
                len++;
              }
            }
            if (len > maxLength) {
              return false;
            } else {
              imgArray.push(f);

              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = function (e) {
                console.log(f.type);
                if (f.type == 'application/pdf') {
                  var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg' ><div class='upload__img-close'></div><img  src='https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/128/337/337946.png'></div></div>";

                } else {
                  var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>";

                }
                imgWrap.append(html);
                iterator++;
              }
              reader.readAsDataURL(f);
            }
          }
        });
      });
    });

    $('body').on('click', ".upload__img-close", function (e) {
      var file = $(this).parent().data("file");
      for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
        if (imgArray[i].name === file) {
          imgArray.splice(i, 1);
          break;
        }
      }
      $(this).parent().parent().remove();
      $(this).parent().children().remove();

    });
  }
});
```

```css
<style>
.upload__box {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.upload__inputfile {
  width: 0.1px;
  height: 0.1px;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.upload__btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 116px;
  padding: 5px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid;
  background-color: #4045ba;
  border-color: #4045ba;
  border-radius: 10px;
  line-height: 26px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.upload__btn:hover {
  background-color: unset;
  color: #4045ba;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.upload__btn-box {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.upload__img-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 0 -10px;
}

.upload__img-box {
  width: 200px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.upload__img-close {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 24px;
  z-index: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.upload__img-close:after {
  content: '\2716';
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
}

.img-bg {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <div class="col-lg-12 mt-4">
    <label for="file">Upload Document (Multiple Document)</label>
    <div class="upload__box">
      <div class="upload__btn-box">
        <label class="upload__btn">
        Upload file
        <input type="file" multiple="" id="files" name="files[]" data-max_length="20" class="upload__inputfile" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg, image/png, application/pdf">
        </label>
      </div>
      <div class="upload__img-wrap"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Please edit your answer and add some explanation of what you changed and what the issue was with OP's code so others can learn. Thanks

Comment: Not a issue that answer but i explain in with run code snippet so i am trying to with output show .  Thanks

Comment: Clear and good answer. It's understandable without explanation. Most people need help to solve their problems. For teaching, studying and explanation they could register for online courses. Thank for your help